# Extend interface of overridden method in ABAP

Tags: methods, overriding, abap, redefinition

As it commonly known, one cannot extend or redefine interface of the overridden method in the inherited ABAP class. [Help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapmethods_redefinition.htm):

> The interface and the category of the method (a general or functional instance method or event handler) are not changed in a redefinition.

This covers both global and local classes redefinition.

What are the probable workarounds of this limitation if one wants to add or remove methods parameters or change their type? Optional parameters is a way, though not very comfy. Any other ways?

Comment: This request violates nearly everything I know about class-focused object orientation. Whyever would you want to do that? The interface is meant to be something dependable. Your override would break exactly this reliability. Imagine you add a static exception, for instance, this would produce syntax errors in all implementers.

Comment: I don't want violate your world's backbone :), I just want to find a workaround, i.e. best practice.

Comment: `Whyever would you want to do that?` sometimes we should inherit a parent class, which cannot be changed. What is usually done in case one need to reimplement its method with some additional interface parameters?

Comment: But what do you want to gain with that? Somebody calls that interface method. They rely on its definition. Even if you now were able to change this definition, how would the caller become aware of that? ABAP would simply reject the call because it lacks some parameters, or the parameters have the wrong type. This is not even ABAP-specific, you'd get the very same in Java and C++ and C#. The only languages that are different are object-focused duck-typers like JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the signature of an interface method in any way in its implementations. This is simply because there is no way to do this that would not produce hard-to-analyze syntax errors at run time. An interface is a contract - any class implementing it promises that it will implement all methods (and variables...) that are present in the interface.

Assume there is a method `METH` of interface `IF1` taking a single parameter `PAR1` of type `TYPE1`. If you now write a class that implements a method `METH` with a single parameter `PAR1` of type `TYPE2`, then you have *not* written a class that implements `IF1`. A caller that passes a parameter of type `TYPE1` to the method of your class will encounter a type conversion error (whether at runtime or at compile time depends somewhat on the genericity of the types).

Therefore, there is no way to change the signature of an interface method in its redefinition without producing such runtime errors - your class does *not* implement the interface. Implementing an interface means that the class will accept exactly the number, type and kind of parameters specified for the methods in the interface. There is literally no use case in which you could meaningfully want to change this while still claiming that your class implements the interface. Whatever you're trying to do, this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own interface, extending the existing interface. Add same method with different parameters. Then create abstract class from your extended interface and fill methods with code for calling real method with setting values to optional parameters. After then create your class from abstract.

```
interface
|--> extented interface
     |--> abstract class
          |--> class
```